# problem roomba 500 power saving scheduler

Tags: irobot-create

anybody experienced problem with power saving and scheduler command?

I have roomba 521 with last firmware updated via OSMO, so now it has also power saving feature.

I have problem with scheduler command: I send command using serial connector, roomba seem to accept my command and it beep to confirm it; but roomba don't start at defined time...

Could be some problem with power saving that prevent scheduler command?

Comment: thought:   it is difficult to start at a set time if you do not know what time it is

Comment: which mean? using command I can setup actual time and scheduling time...please read first roomba specifications...

Comment: it was a guess ... you did not say that the roomba has the correct time of day set

Comment: I had the same thought -- are you sure you've properly set the current time using op code 168 before setting a schedule with op code 167? The robot should run its schedule, even when it's asleep.